# How do I transfer files to a SunOS server via sftp with FileZilla?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, filesystems, files

According to the admin of the webserver, I should be able to use Filezilla to transfer files to the server but I am getting an error.

I set up Filezilla for transferring files sftp - using [these directions](http://www.upenn.edu/computing/help/doc/ftp/filezillasftp.html) I found on the web.

However, this is what I get:

```
Status:    Connecting to server.edu:12345...
Response:    fzSftp started
Command:    open "gmcnulty@server.edu" 12345
Error:    Connection timed out
Error:    Could not connect to server
Status:    Waiting to retry...
Status:    Connecting to server.edu:12345...
Response:    fzSftp started
Command:    open "gmcnulty@server.edu" 12345
Error:    Connection timed out
Error:    Could not connect to server
```

Any point in the right direction would be very helpful.

FYI - I'm able to connect to the remote server using X-Win32 ssh, from my Windows 7 machine (and I do not run this at the same time as Filezilla):

```
SunOS server.edu 5.10 Generic_120011-14 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220
System type is SUN4V with 65408 MB of memory.

server.edu(1):
```

**EDIT: ANSWER**

The port must be set to 22 for ssh, not my user port.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_well-known_ports_%28computing%29#Well-known_ports

Comment: Are you using the same port for SSH and SFTP?

Comment: Edited the question for more clarity, yes I close down the X-Win32 session and then run filezilla...is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I am asking if you are connecting to the same port on both occasions.

Comment: yes, it is the same and correct port in both cases.

Comment: You ought to add your answer as an answer instead of as an edit.  It's okay to add and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

The port must be set to 22 for ssh, not my user port.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_well-known_ports_%28computing%29#Well-known_ports

Comment: Yes, SSH almost exclusively uses port 22.  Any variation on that is often by administrators thinking that using an alternate port (obscurity) will shield them from attack (which is arguable, but whatever).